# Android Compose LazyColumn IllegalArgumentException: Key was already used

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I keep getting IllegalArgumentException: Key was already used. If you are using LazyColumn/Row please make sure you provide a unique key for each item.

I am sure my keys are unique. Here is my sample code:

```
@Composable
fun UiComponent() {
    LazyColumn(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
                state = scrollState,
                reverseLayout = true
            ) {
                items(
                    items = viewmodel.messages,
                    key = { item -> item.hashcode() },
                    itemContent = { item: Entity ->
                        if (item.isDeleted) {
                            //show deleted ui
                        } else {
                            //show messages
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
}

ViewModel {

    init { 
       observeDataFromDB()
    }

    private val _messages: MutableList<Entity> = mutableStateListOf()
    val messages: List<Entity> = _messages


    fun observeDataFromDB() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repo.getData().collect {
                _messages.apply {
                    addNewItem(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


//extensions
fun MutableList<Entity>.addNewItem(entity: Entity) {
    if (this.size >= MAX_SIZE) {
        removeLast()
    }
    Log("existing ${this.toList().map { "${it.hashCode()}" }}")
    Log("adding new ${entity.hashCode()}")
    this.add(0, entity)
}

//id is unique
data class Entity(id:String, isDeleted: Boolean, message: String)
```

I have also tried providing an observable from my Viewmodel(`StateFlow<List<Entity>`) but I get the same error. Also tried setting `id` as the key.

Mostly encountering this issue when items are rapidly added. For example user spamming multiple messages in a short time.

Comment: Kindly add the data class `Entity` code as well.

Comment: Exactly when does the error occur? When you start the app, or when you actually scroll the column?

Comment: When an item gets added to the lazy column

Comment: Even if IDs are unique you still might have data duplicated and that makes LazyColum "think" ids are not unique. So check for duplicates and solve problem there. Rapid messaging causing the issue suggest that it might the case.

Answer (score 5):

If any of your messages are identical, you'll end up with the same hashcode value and this will generate the error. To avoid this, if your messages don't have an id, use `itemsIndexed` instead of just `items` and assign the index as the key:

```
@Composable
fun UiComponent() {
    LazyColumn(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
                state = scrollState,
                reverseLayout = true
            ) {
                items(
                    items = viewmodel.messages,
                    key = { item -> item.id },
                    itemContent = { item: Entity ->
                        if (item.isDeleted) {
                            //show deleted ui
                        } else {
                            //show messages
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: But the id will always be unique. `data class Entity(val id: String, isDeleted: Boolean, val message: String)`. Also, if I use index will any row in `LazyColumn` get recomposed if `isDeleted` in `Entity` changes?

Comment: You're not using an id. You're setting the key to item.hashcode().  I updated my code and replaced the item.hashcode with item.id.

Comment: Still the same error :(

Comment: Print the id from all items to the Log before you call LazyColumn and check to see that they are all unique. I'm pretty sure that you have duplicate items in your list.

Comment: This is not the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is facing similar issue:

For me it got resolved after removing `mutableStateListOf` and using a simple list and observing this list in composable as state.

Basically `StateFlow<List< Entity>>` and in compose `viewmodel.message.collectAsState()`. Finally passing this list to the `lazyColumn`

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is every enter the composable list not recraeting instead of fetching the same list thats why probably app getting crash

Solve: You can create disposable effect when every leave the composable you can use this method List.clear() on OnDispose{}

Hope solve your problem :)

Comment: I guess error key name first index of list right ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does not help when you want to cache the list in a shared viewmodel...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a `Paging` library and `LazyColumn`, setting keys so:

```
LazyColumn(
    state = lazyListState,
) {
    items(
        count = list.itemCount,
        key = { index -> list[index]?.id },
    ) { index -> 
       ...
    }
}
```

But the `list` collection contained non-unique `id`s. So that a server sometimes returned *two equal records*.

In this case you can set key as `null` or random string, or add index.